# If someone talks too low, or mumbles, do you call that 'inaudible' or 'unintelligible'?

Tags: word-choice

To put it more specifically:

- is `inaudible` reserved for when you can't hear *anything*, or does it also apply when you can't hear *enough*?
- is there a more specific word than `unintelligible` to mean 'acoustically unintelligible'?

Comment: I'd say that if you can't understand because it's too soft, then *inaudible* is fine, but if you can't understand because they weren't articulating properly, you should use *unintelligible*. The word *mumble* covers both situations.

Comment: If you use *unintelligible,* you're in good company. From Charles Dickens: *Then he comes back, pounces on the Chinaman, and seizing him with 
both hands by the throat, turns him violently on the bed. The 
Chinaman clutches the aggressive hands, resists, gasps, and 
protests. 

'What do you say?' 

A watchful pause. 

'Unintelligible!'*

Comment: Try plain ol’ English/Germanic instead of fancy Latin, and you will see that there is little difference between *couldn’t hear it, couldn’t make it out, couldn’t understand it, couldn’t tell what they were saying.*  You may be trying to put too fine a point on it by resorting to all these fanciful Latinate sesquipedalianisms. Use shorter words so folks know what you mean.

Comment: *Incoherent* would also work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Inaudible* is used in typed transcripts of taped police interviews where I come from, and covers both cases: it means that the words spoken cannot be heard clearly.

Comment: Is that formalised or just commonplace?

Comment: In all the statement transcriptions I've seen (and there have been quite a few in the course of the day job) it's always been in capitals and angle-brackets: `<INAUDIBLE>`.

Comment: @HannoFietz You aren’t going to get much joy if you go looking for a formalization process in English.  It just doesn’t happen very often.

Comment: @tchrist I took it to mean "formalised in my police force", which it appears to be. Police English is not generally great, but in this instance it actually seems reasonably sensible.

Comment: @tchrist; but courtrooms are one of the few places it does.  Witnesses and police officers are permitted a latitude that lawyers and stenographers are not.

Comment: It's also worth noting that closed captioning on television (at least in the U.S.) also does the same thing, usually using [inaudible] when it can't be heard or [no dialogue] if someone appears to be speaking but is intentionally not meant to be heard.

Answer (score 3):

[Inaudible](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inaudible) is used to describe a sound that is too soft to be heard. The reason why it is too soft is irrelevant. It also does not necessarily have to refer to a voice or speech, and, strictly speaking, implies that the sound cannot be heard at all.

As for alternatives to *unintelligible*, [mutter](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mutter) might be a good choice. To emphasise the unintelligibility of a mutter, it can be described as an *indistinct mutter* or *incoherent mutter* or variants thereof.

Comment: But if a *sentence* is inaudible, it cannot be heard as a sentence, which is not to say no sound can be heard at all.  Similarly a sign may be illegible because too many letters are missing, even though those that remain are perfect.

Comment: @TimLymington It is similar to the sentence, "I could not hear what was being said.". Taken literally, this would mean that you could not hear any sound at all. But in common usage, this could simply mean that you could not understand what was being said. Whether this was because the speaker had, for example, his microphone turned off, or if a crowd around you was too noisy, or if you suffer from a mild form of Presbycusis, will need to be explained further or taken for granted.

Comment: My point was that there is **no** context where your 'strict/literal' meaning applies, unless after a hearing test you ask 'How many inaudible beeps were there?'

Comment: @TimLymington Did you know that the echolocation calls of bats are inaudible to us humans? Dogs, on the other hand, can hear things that are inaudible to us, and see things that are similarly invisible.